# How to configure reporting service using host name (DNS) instead of server name

Tags: reporting-services, https, dns

I would like to access the SQL reports in the SQL reporting server using a hostname (DNS) instead of the server name.

I have added A record in the DNS server mapped to the IP of the reporting server. named as **reports.xxx.com**

now I tried to access the reports using this name **http://reports.xxx.com/reports** instead of **http://server-name/reports** but it does not work.
I have tried to add the hostname in the configuration of the Reporting server but it does not work.

Also, I have added a certificate to the server to access the reports using **https** but it does not work too.

Comment: Besides the fact your question is off-topic here as not related to programming (see [sf] instead probably,or [webmaster.se]), having "but it does not work." is not very helpful in a question. You should write exactly about what you tried (which commands...), what happened (error? if so which one explicitly as displayed as text or timeout? Something else?) and what you expected instead. Also, please do not obfuscate badly: in 99.99% of cases you will get better answers if you give out the real names, but if you REALLY REALLY need to obfuscate use `example.com` as name (or `.example` as TLD)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the domain you're trying to access (e.g. reports.xxx.com) to your vhosts and pointed it to the correct location for the site?

Comment: I have only added A record in the DNS Server mapped to the reporting server.
N. B) IIS not installed in the mentioned server and no other applications hosted on the server.

Comment: Is this a Windows or Linux Server?

Comment: it is a window server

Comment: Right ok, so when you go to the server-name you get a webpage come up?

Comment: yes, but when I tried to access the reports using the DNS created it does not working

Comment: Right ok, are you running any sort of webserver if not IIS?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is if you're just using HTML as that just needs a filesystem otherwise thinks like MySQL and PHP would not function. It would be a case of inspecting what you are using to see what is going wrong.